# Koh Samui to Bangkok or Phuket during New year

Tags: air-travel, budget, thailand

I was checking Air tickets on bangkok air from Koh Samui to Phuket or Bangkok and especially on 2nd January its very very expensive almost 4 times.
This is happening just on 2nd Jan, all other dates its fine (screenshot below)
I am a bit amazed by this and not sure if it is just demand or its a holiday or some event on 2nd January.
Any idea on this.

[image]

Comment: Google Flights shows no direct flights available on that date. So the price is probably for a much longer route?

Comment: Its same for Bangkok, no direct flights on 2nd. Also on 2nd there are no  flights from Samui to Krabi. It looks a bit odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prices you're seeing are very high due to a combination of factors:

- Being a holiday both locally and around the world, plus the best season in terms of weather for much of the country, New Year's is absolute peak season across Thailand and Samui is a very popular tourist destination.
- Samui is a small airport and Bangkok Airways has an effective monopoly on flights, so prices are always higher than most Thai domestic routes.
- The specific 18,000-baht itinerary you're seeing on Jan 2nd is not a direct flight, but a connection via Chiang Mai in the far north of the country, so you're paying for two separate long flights instead of a quick hop.

If you're not happy with what Bangkok Airways is charging, your alternative is to cross over to the mainland by ferry (~90 min) and either continue to Bangkok by cheap domestic flight from any of Surat Thani, Nakhon Si Thammarat or Chumphon, or take a cheap bus across to Phuket.  [Wikivoyage has the full scoop.](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ko_Samui#Flight_and_ferry)

Comment: Connecting flights are typically cheaper than non-stops, despite being a lot more expensive for the airline. It's just their bizarre pricing logic. That's why "hidden city" ticketing exists. I found almost no correlation between distance travelled, number of legs, and price.

Comment: @Hilmar That's normally the case, but Bangkok Airways is a small airline with few connecting passengers, and as far as I can tell their booking engine really does just sum up the individual segments.

Comment: @Hilmar connecting flights are cheaper than non-stops only when they are competing with a non-stop from another airline. When there is no competition or very little, it’s quite common for connecting flights to be much more expensive.